# How do I translate the SkeletonPoint's Value using Kinect SDK before mapping them to the colorImage?

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, xna-4.0, kinect-sdk

I am creating a project on Kinect where I need to translate and rotate the skeleton of the user so that it would be always facing the Kinect.

I do know that I cannot change the actual values of the Skeleton, so I created an avatar skeleton called littleGuy. littleGuy is an array of SkeletonPoints having all the SkeletonPoints of the actual Skeleton assigned to each element respectively.

All manipulations happen to the littleGuy skeleton and then saved in a different skeleton called transGuy (translated guy). The problem is whenever I edit the values of the transGuy and then try to map them to the colorImage, I get an overflow of values and the skeleton is never rendered.

In the below code I assign the Center Hip to littleGuy[0], and then I choose the offset to be -CHip, since all translations will be based on this centerHip. I then add the offset to transGuy.

```
if (joint.JointType == JointType.HipCenter)
                {
                    littleguy_chip = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position;
                    littleGuy[0] = littleguy_chip;

                    TransValue.X = -littleguy_chip.X;
                    TransValue.Y = -littleguy_chip.Y;
                    TransValue.Z = -littleguy_chip.Z;

                    transGuy[0] = littleGuy[0];
                    transGuy[0].X = littleGuy[0].X + TransValue.X;
                    transGuy[0].Y = littleGuy[0].Y + TransValue.Y;
                    transGuy[0].Z = littleGuy[0].Z + TransValue.Z;

                    prevPositions[0] = joint.Position;
                }
```

After that, I draw each joint by looping on transGuy and mapping the value to the skeleton, but I always get the value 2147483648

```
 for (int j = 0; j < transGuy.Length; j++)
                {
                    if ((transGuy[i] == littleguy_head && transGuy[j] == littleguy_cshoulder)
                        || (transGuy[i] == littleguy_cshoulder && transGuy[j] == littleguy_spine)
                        || (transGuy[i] == littleguy_spine && transGuy[j] == littleguy_chip))
                    {
                        var p2 = kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(
                            transGuy[j], ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

                        spriteBatch.Draw(lineTex, new Vector2(p.X + 80, p.Y),
                            null, Color.White, (float)Math.Atan2(p2.Y - p.Y, (p2.X + 80) - (p.X + 80)), new Vector2(0f, (float)lineTex.Height / 2),
                            new Vector2(Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(p.X + 80, p.Y), new Vector2(p2.X + 80, p2.Y)), 1f), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

                    }
```

I really need to manipulate the points before Mapping them to the color image... what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Since the values of X,Y,Z in SkeletonPoint are float. Type Cast to decimal when adding the offset then type cast the whole thing back to float. The new code looks like this:

```
if (joint.JointType == JointType.Spine)
                {
                    littleguy_spine = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Spine].Position;
                    littleGuy[1] = littleguy_spine;

                    transGuy[1] = littleGuy[1];
                    transGuy[1].X = (float)((decimal)(littleGuy[1].X) + (decimal)(TransValue.X));
                    transGuy[1].Y = (float)((decimal)(littleGuy[1].Y) + (decimal)(TransValue.Y));
                    transGuy[1].Z = (float)((decimal)(littleGuy[1].Z) + (decimal)(TransValue.Z));

                    prevPositions[1] = joint.Position;
                }
```